# Ubuntu 18.04 Xonar DG not recognized

Tags: drivers, 18.04, sound, asus

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and I've just bought an Asus Xonar DG sound card to use on my desktop. After several reboots and updates the sound card is not recognized. *Alsamixer* doesn't show the card as an output option.

The following commands show my onboard sound card and the hdmi for my video card, but no Xonar sound card. This is an PCI not a PCI express card btw.

```
ubuntu-pc:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
ubuntu-pc:~$ pacmd list-cards
ubuntu-pc:~$ lspci -vv | grep -i -A 10 audio
```

I'm not seeing a place online to download the drivers either.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After many restarts and PCI error related crashes I have my solution. Disable the onboard audio (Azalia audio on an HP mobo) and change the analog output to multichannel on alsamixer. Hopefully this helps other folks out. I was seriously worried after the crashes with BIOS errors popping up.

Answer (score 0):

The missing drivers caused same problem for me, with Asus Xonar DX soundcard.
First try please :

$ lsmod |grep snd

You should see something like this, quote only:
...
snd_virtuoso           49152  4
snd_oxygen_lib         40960  1 snd_virtuoso
...
snd                    81920  24 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_oxygen_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_virtuoso,snd_mpu401_uart,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
...

If there is no result, you should verify your extra kernel modules, because
the soundcard drivers are in this package :

$ dpkg -l |grep linux-modules-extra

The good result should be same :

ii  linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-21-generic      4.18.0-21.22~18.04.1                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.18.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

Check your actual running kernel version with :

$ uname -a
Linux asus-desktop 4.18.0-21-generic #22~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 16 15:07:19 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The installed (ii) linux-modules-extra package have to be same version :

linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-21-generic

If you do not like commands to handle packages, you can use synaptic GUI :

## apt-get install synaptic

Install the proper version of linux-modules-extra, reboot your pc & listen music :-)

Answer (score 0):

Run alsamixer from the terminal, should be installed by default.

> $ alsamixer

Navigate to the right to Analog Output with the LEFT-RIGHT arrows, then using the UP-DOWN arrows change the output from headphones to MULTICHANNEL.

Close the Alsamixer

You should now have sound.